# Sequlize js conditionally select when inner joins involves

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working on a project where we develop a tourist app. Some items are add to the system as
advertisements (Hotels, Night clubs) and some items add as useful information (beaches,national parks)

I have a table called items.

items

```
id | category_id | name                | is_payment 
1  | 1           | hotel califonia     | 1          
2  | 1           | hotel hilton        | 1          
3  | 2           | Yala national park  | 0          
4  | 2           | Kumana national park| 0
```

here category_id refers the categories table.

categories

```
id | name           | type
1  | Hotels         | commercial
2  | National parks | non-commercial
```

I want to select all the items from the item table.
But if it's a commercial item I need to check whether payment is made or not before display to the end users.

What I have done upto now is

```
const data = await db[model_name].findAndCountAll({
            include: [{
                model: db.Category,
                where: {

                }
            }],
            where: {
                city_id: req.params.id
            }
        })
```

And also my raw query would be something like this

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
JOIN categories c 
ON i.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.type != 'commercial' 
OR (c.type = 'commercial' AND i.is_payment = 1)
```

How do I achieve this using sequelizejs?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help:

```
include: [{
    model: db.Category,
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            {type: {[Op.ne]: 'commercial'}},
            {
                [Op.and]: [
                    {type: 'commercial'},
                    {is_payment: 1}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}],
```

I didn't tested it.
In time, it would be very useful some read on operators section on http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html.